# with python openCV, how can i process image without loss

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

i want to make program that has several functions(translate, rotate, flip,shear..)
but i got problem with implemening the translating function.
when i move image left and then right, left part of the image is lost.
and i think this problem will be same with other functions.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread('tekapo.bmp')

if img is None:
    print("file not found")
    
rows, cols, ch = img.shape

#초기 x, y값 및 기본값 설정
c = (int(cols/2), int(rows/2))

def draw_line(input_img): #input_img에 선, 원 그리고 변형된 이미지 반환
    (x, y) = c
    c_img = input_img.copy()
    cv.line(c_img, c, (640, y), (0, 0, 255), 1) #x축 보조선
    cv.line(c_img, c, (x, 480), (0, 255, 0), 1) #y축 보조선
    cv.circle(c_img, c, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
    return c_img
    
def imshow(input_img): #input_img에 point그리고 출력, input_img는 변형 X
    c_img = input_img.copy()
    cv.imshow('C_img', draw_line(c_img))
    

def click_mouse(e, x, y, d, p):
    if e == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        global c
        c = (int(x), int(y)) #좌표 저장
        imshow(copy_img)
        
    
def translate(input_img, dx, dy):
    rows, cols, ch = input_img.shape
    M = np.float32([[1, 0, dx], [0, 1, dy]])
    c_img = input_img.copy()
    c_img2 = cv.warpAffine(c_img, M, (cols, rows))
    img = c_img2.copy()
    imshow(c_img2)
    return img



copy_img = img.copy() #변형시킬 이미지가 담길 변수
imshow(copy_img)

cv.setMouseCallback('C_img', click_mouse, copy_img)

while True:
    key = cv.waitKey()
    if key == ord('t'):#오른쪽 아래로 가는 기능
        copy_img = translate(copy_img, 5, 5)
    elif key == ord('e'):#왼쪽 위로 가는 기능
        copy_img = translate(copy_img, -5, -5)
    elif key == 27:
        print(c)
        break

cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

i've saw similar problem from here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75388906/how-to-rotate-and-translate-an-image-with-opencv-without-losing-off-screen-data)

but i think that looks little different situation with mine.

i want to process image without losing part of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of updating the image, we may update the transformation matrix `M`, and apply `warpAffine` to the original image.
That way we are preserving the original image and only modifying the transformation matrix each time the relevant key is pressed.

---

- Initialize matrix `M` with "eye" transformation (without the third row):

  ```
   M = np.float64([[1, 0, 0], 
                   [0, 1, 0]])
  ```
- Instead of using `translate`, implement a method that updates matrix `M`.
  `M` is updated by changing the translation and the current `M`.
  Changing is applied by multiplying the translation matrix from the left, as described in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75391691/4926757):

  ```
   def translate_mat(M, dx, dy):
       # Instead of updating the image, update the transformation matrix M
       T0 = np.vstack((M, np.array([0, 0, 1])))  # Add row [0, 0, 1] to the bottom of M ([0, 0, 1] applies last row of eye matrix), T0 is 3x3 matrix.

       # Translation matrix (3x3)
       T1 = np.float64([[1, 0, dx], 
                        [0, 1, dy],
                        [0, 0, 1 ]])

       T = T1 @ T0  # Chain transformations (multiply translation matrix T1 by the input translation matrix).
       M = T[0:2, :]  # Remove the last row from T (the last row of affine transformations is always [0, 0, 1] and OpenCV conversion is omitting the last row).
       return M  # Return updated M (after applying the translation on the input M).
  ```
- In the while loop, update `M` and apply `warpAffine` to `img` (instead of updating `copy_img`):

  ```
   while True:
       key = cv.waitKey()
       if key == ord('t'):#오른쪽 아래로 가는 기능
           # copy_img = translate(copy_img, 5, 5)
           M = translate_mat(M, 5, 5)  # Apply transformation to transformation matrix M instead of modifying the image.
           copy_img = cv.warpAffine(img, M, (cols, rows))  # Apply warp to the original image
           imshow(copy_img)
  ```

---

Code sample:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread('tekapo.bmp')

if img is None:
    print("file not found")
    
rows, cols, ch = img.shape

#초기 x, y값 및 기본값 설정
c = (int(cols/2), int(rows/2))

def draw_line(input_img): #input_img에 선, 원 그리고 변형된 이미지 반환
    (x, y) = c
    c_img = input_img.copy()
    cv.line(c_img, c, (640, y), (0, 0, 255), 1) #x축 보조선
    cv.line(c_img, c, (x, 480), (0, 255, 0), 1) #y축 보조선
    cv.circle(c_img, c, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
    return c_img
    
def imshow(input_img): #input_img에 point그리고 출력, input_img는 변형 X
    c_img = input_img.copy()
    cv.imshow('C_img', draw_line(c_img))
    

def click_mouse(e, x, y, d, p):
    if e == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        global c
        c = (int(x), int(y)) #좌표 저장
        imshow(copy_img)
        
    
#def translate(input_img, dx, dy):
#    rows, cols, ch = input_img.shape
#    M = np.float32([[1, 0, dx], [0, 1, dy]])
#    c_img = input_img.copy()
#    c_img2 = cv.warpAffine(c_img, M, (cols, rows))
#    img = c_img2.copy()
#    imshow(c_img2)
#    return img

def translate_mat(M, dx, dy):
    # Instead of uprating the image, update the translation matrix M
    T0 = np.vstack((M, np.array([0, 0, 1])))  # Add row [0, 0, 1] to the bottom of M ([0, 0, 1] applies last row of eye matrix), T0 is 3x3 matrix.

    # Translation matrix (3x3)
    T1 = np.float64([[1, 0, dx], 
                     [0, 1, dy],
                     [0, 0, 1 ]])

    T = T1 @ T0  # Chain transformations (multiply translation matrix T1 by the input translation matrix).
    M = T[0:2, :]  # Remove the last row from T (the last row of affine transformations is always [0, 0, 1] and OpenCV conversion is omitting the last row).
    return M  # Return updated M (after applying the translation on the input M).




copy_img = img.copy() #변형시킬 이미지가 담길 변수
imshow(copy_img)

cv.setMouseCallback('C_img', click_mouse, copy_img)

# Initialize M to "eye" transformation (without the third row).
M = np.float64([[1, 0, 0], 
                [0, 1, 0]])

rows, cols, ch = img.shape

while True:
    key = cv.waitKey()
    if key == ord('t'):#오른쪽 아래로 가는 기능
        # copy_img = translate(copy_img, 5, 5)
        M = translate_mat(M, 5, 5)  # Apply transformation to transformation matrix M instead of modifying the image.
        copy_img = cv.warpAffine(img, M, (cols, rows))  # Apply warp to the original image
        imshow(copy_img)
    elif key == ord('e'):#왼쪽 위로 가는 기능
        # copy_img = translate(copy_img, -5, -5)
        M = translate_mat(M, -5, -5)  # Apply transformation to transformation matrix M instead of modifying the image.
        copy_img = cv.warpAffine(img, M, (cols, rows))  # Apply warp to the original image
        imshow(copy_img)
    elif key == 27:
        print(c)
        break

cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Sample image after pressing `'t'` 10 times:
[image]

Sample image after pressing `'t'` 10 times and then pressing `'e'` 20 times:
[image]